# How to find the age of the universe from fundamental constants?

Tags: gravity, universe, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

PAM Dirac had found a number with dimension time using fundamental constants like mass of electron, universal gravitational constant, speed of light and so on.
This number that he had found coincided with the age of the universe.
How to replicate his formula for age of universe? What will be the actual relation?

This is also known as Dirac's Coincidence,
or Dirac's Large Number Hypothesis.

Some references:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_large_numbers_hypothesis

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_large_numbers_hypothesis#Dirac's_interpretation_of_the_large_number_coincidences

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/500308/